# Meaning of "in the way their culture dictates"

Tags: meaning

Please tell me the meaning of *in the way their culture dictates* in the following sentence:

> In this documentary we meet many girls from across the world, as they come of age **in the way their culture dictates**, we see remarkable heart-warming stories of bravery and humor.

Comment: Can you tell us why you need the phrase explained? What don't you understand? What have you found out so far?

Comment: Maybe it is just because of my ignorance. Honestly, I don't understand the meaning of this sentence. Maybe a conjunction is missing or I am missing an important point.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coming_of_age) is often a good place to begin one's research. // The two commas are incorrect; I'd replace the second with a period.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'd replace the first. We see heart-warming stories as the girls come of age. (Presumably this refers to what is now known as FGM.)

Answer (score 3):

The term "come of age" here is a reference to the social transition from being a child to being a young adult.  This would include the person's roles, rights and responsibilities.

The nature of the "coming of age" will therefore depend on the culture of that society.  For instance, here may be particular rituals, ceremonies or events.